# How to get user's photos in a general view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, instance

I'm trying to make an alert that shows up in every view (I've put it in `application.html.erb`), that only shows up if the user (current_user) hasn't uploaded any photo yet.

The thing is, I don't know how to put my controllers in order to retrieve `user.photos` and check if it's `blank`.

**In my view**

```
<% if @user.photos.blank? %>
  <div class="alert-header">
    <i class="icon-cog green"> </i> Todavía no has subido ningún spot  
    <button class="semi_margin_left smallbutton medium"> Sube uno </button>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've tried to put in my `pages controller`:

```
@user = current_user
@photos = @user.photos
```

It will give me an error when doing logout.

The question is, what controller do I need to touch if I want @user.photos to be available in all of the app? The alert is going to show up in the whole app.

Thanks

Comment: `@user.photos`, and `@user` on its whole, should be available anywhere you make it available. In which view is the code you provided from?

Answer (score 0):

Add helper method to application controller:

```
# application_controller.rb
before_action :check_photos_alert

def check_photos_alert
   @show_photo_alert = @user && @user.photos.blank?
end
```

**Just make sure that @user is being set before this action is being invoked.** Then in your view you can check whether @show_photo_alert flag is set.

```
<% if @show_photo_alert %>
   <div class="alert-header">
     <i class="icon-cog green"> </i> Todavía no has subido ningún spot  
     <button class="semi_margin_left smallbutton medium"> Sube uno </button>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

One point to note though: ApplicationController is a parent class for most if not all of your controllers so it might be too much to perfom this check on every request. If such is the case, move this logic from ApplicationController to a module and include this module to every controller you need this check.